# Delete contents of temp folder

Tags: powershell, directory, temp

I've got the following code snippet which currently removes everything in my temp directory and re-adds a new temp directory.

```
if($serverVersion.name -like "*2003*"){
    $dir = "\\$server" + '\C$\WINDOWS\Temp\*'
    remove-item $dir -force -recurse
    if($?){new-item -path "\\$server\admin$\Temp" -Type Directory}
}
elseif($serverVersion.name -like "*2008*"){
    $dir = "\\$server" + '\C$\Windows\Temp\*'
    remove-item $dir -force -recurse
    if($?){New-Item -Path "\\$server\admin$\Temp" -Type Directory}  
}
```

I'm trying to slightly alter the code to where it will no longer delete the temp directory and instead simply remove all of the contents inside of temp. I added `\*` at the end of my `$dir` variable so that it tries to get all of the items inside of temp rather than deleting Temp itself. When I run this however I'm not deleting anything. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do this and figure it may be useful for someone in the future.

```
if($serverVersion.name -like "*2003*"){
    $dir = "\\$server" + '\C$\WINDOWS\Temp'
    Get-ChildItem -path $dir -Recurse | %{Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force}
    if($?){new-item -path "\\$server\admin$\Temp" -Type Directory}
}
elseif($serverVersion.name -like "*2008*"){
    $dir = "\\$server" + '\C$\Windows\Temp'
    Get-ChildItem -path $dir -Recurse | %{Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force}
    write-host "success?"
    if($?){New-Item -Path "\\$server\admin$\Temp" -Type Directory}  
}
```

Using get-childitem it will look at everything inside of Temp without deleting Temp itself.

Comment: You don't need %{ } around Remove-Item. It accepts an array (from Get-ChildItem) as input.

Comment: One thing I don't get is why you're differentiating between 2003 and 2008 when your code is the same in both blocks.  Unless you're thinking that the directory path is case sensitive, which it isn't in Windows.

Comment: This is just a small code snippet, it gets a lot more than just temp and certain things that it gets have different paths.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, so long as you meet the pre-reqs and have full control over all files/folders under Temp

```
# Prerequisites
# Must have the PowerShell ActiveDirectory Module installed
# Must be an admin on the target servers
#
# however if you have no permissions to some folders inside the Temp,
# then you would need to take ownship first.
#
$Server = "server Name"
$dir = "\\$Server\admin$\Temp\*"
$OS = (Get-ADComputer $Server -Properties operatingsystem).operatingSystem
IF (($os -like "*2003*") -or ($os -like "*2008*"))
{
    remove-item $dir -Recurse -force
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the PowerShell help file for `remove-item`, the `-recurse` parameter is faulty. It recommends that you `get-childitem` and pipe to `remove-item`. See example from the help file below.

```
-------------------------- EXAMPLE 4 --------------------------

C:\PS>get-childitem * -include *.csv -recurse | remove-item
```

Comment: The faulty -recurse behaviour was fixed in V4.

Comment: The user didn't specify which version of PowerShell is being used.

Comment: No, but if he's got  V4, he won't find the reference to it being faulty in his help.